# Is this the disjunctive and conjunctive nromal form for my porpositional formula F?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I want to bring the following formula $ F = A \land (A \lor B) \Rightarrow (B \lor C)$ into conjunctive normal form (CNF) and disjunctive normal form. Therefore, I applied the following 5 step transformation process:

1. Step: Removing the implication:

$$ \Leftrightarrow \neg (A \land(A \lor B)) \lor (B \lor C)$$

2. Step: Resolve the negation:
   $$ \Leftrightarrow  \neg A \lor (\neg A \land \neg B) \lor (B \lor C)$$
3. Step: Remove parenthesis to receive DNF
   $$ \Leftrightarrow  \neg A \lor (\neg A \land \neg B) \lor B \lor C$$
4. Step: Resolve the absorption based on step 2:
   $$  \neg A \lor (B \lor C)$$
5. Step Removing parenthesis to have DNF as well as CNF:
   $$  \neg A \lor B \lor C$$

I just have three questions to my normal forms:

1. Is this transformation process correct?
2. Is the formula of step 3: $ \neg A \lor (\neg A \land \neg B) \lor B \lor C$ in DNF?
3. Are DNF and CNF of step 5 correct? Is it necessary to remove the parenthesis for DNF and CNF?

Comment: In step 2, the $\lor$s should become $\land$s.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley thanks for your hint! I corrected it. Could you also please answer my questions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you're asking, sorry. Also, you need to carry the change into steps 4 and 5, they should be $\sim A \lor B \lor C$

Comment: @JoshuaTilley thanks, I updated the equations. So the first question is answered by you. thanks a lot. I hope here is anybody who can answer the 2. one!

Comment: The answer to 2 is yes, since it is a disjunction of conjunctions. As for 3, the parentheses make no difference in this case, since $\lor$ is associative.

Comment: thanks @JoshuaTilley, you have helped me a lot!